# Error while uploading iPhone app to appStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, application-loader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with Icon.png (Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627697/problem-with-icon-png-icon-specified-in-the-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top)

I have built an iPhone app and I have tested it on real device, everything is fine.
But when I am using the Application Loader to upload it to appStore I am always getting the following error.

**Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png
iPhone/iPod touch: Info.plist unable to verify icon dimension, no icon found. You must define CFBundleIconFile, CFBundleIconFiles, or provide a default Icon.png the is 57*57.**

I don't know why this error is coming although, I have put the icon in resources folder

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you must set icon for iphone app..!

Comment: @Dinesh, thanks for replay already i have added it.

Comment: @Ishank, i put it there as Icon.png

Comment: @Ishank, it is the same.

Comment: try to delete line icon.png in info.plist and retry assign icon for your app and clean your project!

Comment: @Dinesh, already i tried that.