# XCode 4.5 can't validate app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

When I try to validate a app I get this error message:

```
(null):  Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper:  (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

Often this is caused by missing/corrupt icon file, but not in this case. 
I have opened the archive and found the following line in info.plist file in the `IconPath` list:

```
Applications/xxxxx.app/_CodeSignature
```

This line is not specified in the in-app plist file, and I guess this is the course to the error.

Any idea whats wrong? It's a pretty old project, so something might have changed in xcode.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Icon.png (Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627697/problem-with-icon-png-icon-specified-in-the-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top)

Comment: Similar symptoms, different course. I have already tried the different suggestions in the linked thread without any luck. Unfortunately

Comment: It's a good practice to include the links to the questions you searched trough in your question (so we know you've seen and test all that). I'd try deleting IconPath key alltogether (make a backup first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a problem with our custom XCode project template. The template dates back to XCode 3.x. New projects created with this template seems to have this problem in XCode 4.5. I moved the files to a new project created with one of Apple's standard project templates and the problem went away.